# reactjs-select + react-google-places-autocomplete: how to initialize with a place

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-google-places-autocomplete

I am using a ready made component from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-places-autocomplete for google autocomplete places

But I want to initialize it with place. (because when i edit a form, i have to show the place there)

```
import React from "react";
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from "react-google-places-autocomplete";

const GooglePlacesAutocompleteComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    />
  </div>
);

export default Component;
```

The above is the component

and use is as

```
<GooglePlacesAutocompleteComponent />}
```

I know `react-google-places-autocomplete` uses `react-select` `AsyncSelect`

```
    <AsyncSelect
      {...selectProps}
      loadOptions={fetchSuggestions}
      getOptionValue={({ value }) => value.place_id}
    />
```

the fetchsugestions is list of {label and value}

HOw to pass the intial value

Answer (score 0):

This is best achieved following the docs of React-Select as suggested by the creator. But to achieve what you want to do, you'll need React State.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from "react-google-places-autocomplete"

const Places = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  //our default data

  useEffect(() => {
    data === "" ? setData("") : setData(data.label);
  }, [data]);
  // updating our default data

  return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_API_KEY}
      autocompletionRequest={{
        componentRestrictions: {
          country: ["ng"] //to set the specific country
        }
      }}
      selectProps={{
        defaultInputValue: data, //set default value
        onChange: setData, //save the value gotten from google
        placeholder: "Start Destination",
        styles: {
          input: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#222222"
          }),
          option: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#222222"
          }),
          singleValue: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#222222"
          })
        }
      }}
      onLoadFailed={(error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default Places;
```

We use useEffect to update the defualt value we set on condition that we are getting an actual value. If we're not getting actual value, we're not saving it.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me.

```
import {
    useState,
    useEffect
} from "react"
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from "react-google-places-autocomplete"

const Places = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");
    //our default data

    useEffect(() => {
        data === "" ? setData("") : setData(data.label);
    }, [data]);
    // updating our default data

    return ( <
        GooglePlacesAutocomplete apiKey = {
            process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_API_KEY
        }
        autocompletionRequest = {
            {
                componentRestrictions: {
                    country: ["ng"] //to set the specific country
                }
            }
        }
        selectProps = {
            {
                defaultInputValue: data, //set default value
                onInputChange:(newVal)=>setData(newVal),
                onChange: setData, //save the value gotten from google
                placeholder: "Start Destination",
                styles: {
                    input: (provided) => ({
                        ...provided,
                        color: "#222222"
                    }),
                    option: (provided) => ({
                        ...provided,
                        color: "#222222"
                    }),
                    singleValue: (provided) => ({
                        ...provided,
                        color: "#222222"
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        onLoadFailed = {
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        />
    )
}

export default Places;
```